Как настроить функционал телеграм бота по размещению постов
Всем привет. Познакомился с телеграм ботом @donatelikebot
Не могу понять каким образом реализовал вообще его функционал.
То есть мы можем в абсолютно любом канале написать @donatelikebot и после ввести текст поста.
По постом автоматически появляются кнопки для доната.
Но со стороны разработчика не могу понять как это вообще реализовано.
Есть идеи?
Пока делать ничего не пытался, потому что даже не знаю куда копать

Скорее всего обычный бот на основе aiogram/python-telegram-bot, который обрабатывает сообщение, после обработки события создает кнопки, а после сохраняет информацию о пользователях или транзакциях, используя какую-нибудь СУБД

А вы попробовали вообще его? При упоминании бота в строке ввода текста @donatelikebot Сразу появляется сообщение всплывающее. Это как вообще? И изменяется подсказка на "Текст поста".
